# VB.NET - convert JSON data into array

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net

I have a JSON result that I am trying to convert into an array using *Newtonsoft.Json*.
My JSON result i get from the website is along the lines of (formated for readability):

```
{
"headers":  
    [
        "Shift Date",
        "Shift Number"
    ],
"values":
    [
        ["2016-06-19T00:00:00",0],
        ["2016-06-19T00:00:00",2],
        ["2016-06-19T00:00:00",1]
    ]
}
```

Code examples I have found say that i should be able to use

```
Dim arr As JArray = JArray.Parse(response.Content)
```

This results in an error though with:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: Error reading JArray from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an array: StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

Any guidance on what could be causing the issue? I suspect it is something with the "headers" but unable to find online any suggestions on how to resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `JArray` but your input is actually an object - i.e. the data is

`{..stuff..}`

rather than

`[ {..stuff..} ]`.

If you restructure your input to be:

```
[{
    "headers": [
        "Shift Date",
        "Shift Number"
    ],
    "values": [
        ["2016-06-19T00:00:00", 0],
        ["2016-06-19T00:00:00", 2],
        ["2016-06-19T00:00:00", 1]
    ]
}]
```

You can then use the `JArray.Parse(strJson)` method.

In the current structure, you should use `JObject.Parse`.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have much control over what the data looks like (comes from an external website).
If i just add the square brackets my array has 2 columns and one line. What would be the way to process this into a datatable of sorts so that i can then work with the data? If i use the JObject, does it give an array or a single item (Apologies as this is all new to me)

Comment: @StephenPefanis - I think that the method to convert the Json to a datatable constitutes a new question! Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it helped you out.

Comment: No worries. Thanks Robin. Will accept as it has solved the initial query.